# How can i pass list to template at Golang

Tags: go

I want to use a query which looks like

```
rows:= db.Query("SELECT * FROM names")

var name string

for rows.Next() {
    rows.Scan(&name)
}

//There should be a map

t.Execute(w,p)
```

I want to shape up this to list all names in template like

```
{{range .name}}
{{.}}
{{end}}
```

How can i exactly do that?

Comment: You are not creating a list of names. Also check this link: https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Variables

Comment: You are right but i am looking for working example.

Comment: One thing to be noted. The variable name is not exported and as a result can't be used in go's templating.

Comment: @reticentroot I'm not too sure how true that is. Maybe if you are using [Revel](https://revel.github.io/) yes, but in the basic [text/template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) I don't think so.

Comment: @Acidic check out this article https://medium.com/@IndianGuru/understanding-go-s-template-package-c5307758fab0  exported fields should be used and can even cause crashes, try it in the playground.

Comment: @reticentroot ah yeah, for structs I know. Sorry, I thought you meant for the variable names too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Something Like This?**

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT name FROM names")
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
}

names := make([]string, 0)

for rows.Next() {
    var name string

    err := rows.Scan(&name)
    if err != nil {
        // Handle error
        continue
    }

    names = append(names, name)
}

t := template.New("index")
t, _ = t.Parse(`{{range .}}{{.}} {{end}}`)
t.Execute(w, names)
```

---

**Things to Note**

- You should generally avoid using `*` in your sql queries to make it clear what fields are being selected
- If any fields in your database table **can be** `NULL`, then use `sql.NullBool`, `sql.NullFloat64`, `sql.NullInt64` or `sql.NullString` to avoid possible errors

---

**Possible Output**

```
Bob Jim David Henry Jerry
```

Comment: you are great thank you, that's what i am looking for!

Comment: If this was the solution for you, please consider accepting it as your answer :)